# Ways of spending money combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose person X has $12$ dollars.In each of the first 5 days he buys **one** of the following items.

1.Item A for $1

2.Item B for $2

3.Item C for $3.

In how many ways can he spend the money during the first five days?

This is what I did.

Each of the five days he can buy Item A without running out of money.
Also each of the five days he can buy Item B without running out of money.Therefore based on these 2 choices he has 2 selections each day.Thus $2^5$selections.
Now if he decides to buy item C,
If he buys Item C for 1 day then, still all other four days have 2 choices each day.Ways of selecting the day to buy item C=${5 \choose 1}$ .And each 4 days having 2 choices make the total number of selections=$2^4*5=80$.

If he buys Item C for 2 days then ways of selecting these two days =${5 \choose 1}$.All other three days have 2 choices each day.Total selections in this case=$2^3*10=80$.

If he buys Item C for 3 days then ways of selecting these two days =${5 \choose 2}$
There are 3 ways of selecting items for the next two days.Thus total number of selections for this case=$3*10=30$

Therefore total number of ways of spending 12 dollars is
$2^5+80+80+30=222$.

Is this correct.

Comment: Does order matter? Or does only the final shopping bag matter?

Comment: It is correct if order matters.

Answer (score 1):

So basically if order matters your universe is $\{1,2,3\}^5$ (cardinal $3^5=243$).

I would simply count how many of these quintuplets $(a_1,...,a_5) \in \{1,2,3\}^5$ do *not* satisfy $a_1+...+a_5 \le 12$ by distinguishing how many "$3$" values they have :

- 5 times "3" : only one tuple $(3,3,3,3,3)$
- 4 times "3" : fives tuples where "1" is the fifth value (from $(1,3,3,3,3)$ to $(3,3,3,3,1)$) and five ones where "2" is the last value
- 3 times "3" : only those where the two other values are "2", I count $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to place the two "2"s

Answer : $243 - 1 - 5 - 5 - 10 = 222$.

Answer (score 0):

This is trickier, are number of sums to a limited quantity. You can calculate it using a generating function or by hand knowing the limitations.

Using a generating function will be the sum of the coefficients from the power 5 to 12 of this polynomial

$$f(x)=(x+x^2+x^3)^5=x^{15}+5x^{14}+15x^{13}+30x^{12}+45x^{11}+51x^{10}+45 x^9+30 x^8+15x^7+5 x^6+x^5\\ \to f^*(x)=30x^{12}+45x^{11}+51x^{10}+45 x^9+30 x^8+15x^7+5 x^6+x^5\\
f^*(1)=222$$

Im not consumist so I prefer the version where you can choose DONT buy if you want, in this version the generating function will be

$$g(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3)^5=x^{15}+5 x^{14}+15 x^{13}+35x^{12}+65 x^{11}+101x^{10}+135 x^9+155 x^8+155x^7+135 x^6+101 x^5+65x^4+35 x^3+15 x^2+5 x+1\\ \to g^*(x)=35x^{12}+65 x^{11}+101x^{10}+135 x^9+155 x^8+155x^7+135 x^6+101 x^5+65x^4+35 x^3+15 x^2+5 x+1\\
g^*(1)=1003$$

;)

Comment: Does g represent the ordered selection and f the unordered

Comment: @clarkson, all are ordered/unordered. Order doesnt matter for this problem. $g(x)$ is a version of the original question but considering that you can NOT buy too, i.e., spent 0$ if you want any day.

Comment: Everyday during these 5 days he buys something

Comment: Guy, you read what I write?

Answer (score 0):

If we understand the probleme as this: 
What is the number of ways to spend 12 dollars in 5 days if we have to buy only one item a day, which costs 1 or 2 or 3 dollars?

It is the number of ways to partition 12 in 5 parts, with each of these 5 parts are 1 or 2 or 3:

$1 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 3 =12$ 
all the permutations: $\frac{5!}{3!} =20$

$2 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 =12$ 
all the permutations: $\frac{5!}{3!2!} =10$

So, $20+10 =30$ ways

Cheers

Comment: you don't need to spend the whole 12 dollars in the problem